# Why tasks are not going in parallel?

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I have number of locations(called Cells) where I run tests. Tests are implemented as asynchronous tasks and running consequently. User can select to run any tests for each cell. If I select to run same exactly same tests on all cells, then it's going more or less parallel.

Having tests `A, B, C`, if on cell 1 and 2 I select test `A, B` and on 3 I select only `C`, then for some reason tests in cell 1 and 2 will start running, but in cell 3 test C will not start, until A and B tests in cell 1 and 2 will not finished. Basically all tests in all cells are tend to run in the same order. That is not what I wanted. What I tried to achieve is the chain of tests to run independently from each cell. Now I will show how I implemented.

```
private async void buttonStartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects.Cast<Cell>().ToList();
    if (cells == null)
        return;

    var blockPrepare = CreateExceptionCatchingTransformBlock(new Func<Cell, Task<Cell>>(Tests.Prepare), new Action<Exception, Cell>(HandleUnhandledException), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 10000,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 40,
    });

    var blockFinalize = CreateExceptionCatchingActionBlock(new Func<Cell, Task>(Tests.Finalize), new Action<Exception, Cell>(HandleUnhandledException), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 10000,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 40,
    });

    List<IPropagatorBlock<Cell, Cell>> blockList = new List<IPropagatorBlock<Cell, Cell>>();
    var funcs = tests.Select(x => x.Value);
    foreach (var func in funcs)
    {
        var blockNew = CreateExceptionCatchingTransformBlock(new Func<Cell, Task<Cell>>(func), new Action<Exception, Cell>(HandleUnhandledException), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 10000,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 40,
        });
        blockList.Add(blockNew);
    }

    // link
    for (int i = 0; i < blockList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var b1 = blockList[i];
        var b2 = blockList[i + 1];
        b1.LinkTo(b2);
    }

    // link first and last
    blockPrepare.LinkTo(blockList[0], new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    blockList[blockList.Count - 1].LinkTo(blockFinalize, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    foreach (Cell c in cells)
    {
        c.Reset();
        c.State = Cell.States.InProgress;
        var progressHandler = new Progress<string>(value =>
        {
            c.Status = value;
        });

        c.Progress = progressHandler as IProgress<string>;
        blockPrepare.Post(c);
    };

    blockPrepare.Complete();
    try
    {
        await blockFinalize.Completion;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Debug(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Above you can see 2 mandatory blocks for each cell - prepare and finalize. Here is how I create them:

```
public IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput> CreateExceptionCatchingTransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(
                Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
                Action<Exception, Cell> exceptionHandler,
                ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions)
{
    return new TransformManyBlock<TInput, TOutput>(async input =>
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await transform(input);
            return new[] { result };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionHandler(ex, (input as Cell));

            return Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>();
        }
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);
}

public ITargetBlock<TInput> CreateExceptionCatchingActionBlock<TInput>(
                Func<TInput, Task> action,
                Action<Exception, Cell> exceptionHandler,
                ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions)
{
    return new ActionBlock<TInput>(async input =>
    {
        try
        {
            await action(input);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionHandler(ex, (input as Cell));
        }
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);
}
```

Test itself look like this:

```
public static async Task<Cell> TestDoorsAsync(Cell c)
{
    int thisTestID = TEST_DOORS;
    TestConfiguration conf = c.GetConfiguration(thisTestID);
    if (conf.Enabled)
    {
       ... // execute test
    }
    else
    {
       // report that test was skipped due to user configuration
    }

    return c;
}
```

So is there some option that I missed or software design is wrong, which is preventing tests in cells to run without waiting for the tests to complete in other cells?

UPDATE

The [repo](https://github.com/acidos/DataFlowDemo) is minimal console app demonstrating the issue.

There are still 3 cells and 3 tests(tasks). On cell 1, 2 I am selecting to run all tests, while on cell 3 only test 3. What I expect is right after preparation task for cell 3, to immediately see skipped tests 1, 2 and running test 3.

What I see is (# - cell number)

```
#1 Preparing...
#2 Preparing...
#3 Preparing...

#1 Test1 running...
#2 Test1 running...
#3 Test1 skipped
#1 Test2 running...
#2 Test2 running...
#3 Test2 skipped
#1 Test3 running...
#2 Test3 running...
#3 Test3 running...

#2 Finalizing...
#1 Finalizing...
#3 Finalizing...
```

tests in cell 3 synchronized with tests in cell 1 and 2. All tests finished at the same time, while in cell 3 the single test should have been finished earlier than in other cells.

Comment: Based on your example given: You have a linearly connected set of `TransformBlocks`, assuming those are executing your "A,B,C" functions. If block 1, 2 & 3 are associated with function A,B,C respectivly how do you prevent block 1 & 2 from executing on cell 3, which only had test C selected?

Comment: @JSteward: Inside test function I have data whether to skip C for cell 3 or execute. Updating example...

Comment: Nothing in the currently posted code would cause the behavior you've described. The next place to look would be in the implementation details of your tests. Another option is to set the blocks to log or print exactly which one has what piece of data when to follow your flow. A few oddities though: `MaxParallelism=40`, and `BoundedCapacity=10000` seem high, could these not be unbounded? Also, I don't see the need for a `TransformManyBlock` that doesn't appear to produce an actual collection. Finally, it would be useful to confirm exactly what's flowing where and then you can debug further.

Comment: @JSteward: Do you mean set `BoundedCapacity` to 0? I've changed `TransformManyBlock` to `TransformBlock`, but the problem still remains. I'm going to make a minimalistic console application depicting the problem.

Comment: A console application repro would be very useful. The `TransformManyBlock` was definitely not the source of the issue but it simply appeared out of place. Setting the bounded capacity to `BoundedCapacity = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` i.e. -1 would leave your blocks unbound and accept all incoming `Cells` unless you really are throttling the flow to handle 10,000 messages at any given time. Unbounded is also the default if you do not specify the option.

Comment: @JSteward Please see the [repo](https://github.com/acidos/DataFlowDemo) demonstrating the issue. I will update my original post to show what I expected from demo app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the edit. Add `EnsureOrdered = false` to block options.  What's happening is that your `TransfomrBlocks` are not passing the cells along until they are all done processing, so they can maintain your order. This is default and usually preferable but not in your case.

Looks like I was wrong when I commented that their was nothing wrong in the current code.

Comment: I'm using latest stable version of DataFlow 4.5.24.0 and it seems there is no `EnsureOrdered` in `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`.

Comment: You're on the wrong package. Install System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, the package starting with Microsoft was the original and should no longer be used.

Comment: Unbelievable, it seems to be working as expected, without waiting for other cells! Let me test this a little then I will get back to you. Thanks for detailed understand of the problem! Special thanks for pointing out on using old library.

Comment: Works just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say it for sure, but there are two flaws I can see in your code for sure:

1. You're not propagating the completion between transform blocks in your list
2. You're using the blocking synchronous method to deliver the message: `.Post` instead of `SendAsync`, which is clearly is what you need to get an async flow here. So the last ones had to wait before first ones will finish.

Also, you need to understand that using `BoundedCapacity` introduces throttling into your pipeline, so you should check the buffer sizes, maybe a lot of threads just waits for a place in queue to become available.

Yet another thing you can try is to level the [`DataflowBlockOptions.MaxMessagesPerTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.maxmessagespertask.aspx) property. This property is used for cases when one greedy block proceeds with execution very quick, and handles more and more messages, without letting other blocks to do their job. Internally, each block has a `Task`, in which the handling is being done, and the default is -1, which indicates an unlimited number of messages. By setting this to some positive number, you force the block to restart it's internal task and provide some space to other ones.

For more advanced tips, please, refer to [official docs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782).

Comment: 1. `PropagateCompletion = true` is already there
2. I've tried `SendAsync` and result is same. Later tests are not starting before earlier tests are finished.

Comment: I can only see the propagation on start and on finish, not between them. Added some more thoughts.

Comment: Adding `b1.LinkTo(b2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });` to the rest of blocks didn't change anything as well as increasing MaxMessagesPerTask. What I am not sure is whether for each cell I have to create new set of blocks [prepare, test blocks, finalize] or I as I am doing now create one set and send to first block data.

Comment: Max messages per task shouldn't be very big. As for other question - if you're posting to the same blocks, then you need to know that blocks do their processing with saving the messages's **order**, so you have to either post new messages in parallel, or create pipeline for all the tests you have.