# Parallelness within and across TPL Dataflow blocks?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have some problems about the parallelness within and across TPL Dataflow blocks.

1. Within block: I have a TransformBlock, with let's say MaxDOP of 4, performing things that I already know would benefit if 
   it is as parallel as possible but the scheduler doesn't know. So when I give it 200 items, instead of roughly doing 50 items on 4 threads, it is usually like 150 item on 1 thread, 20 on 2 threads, and then it didn't bothered to use a fourth thread. Is there someway to hint it to be more parallel?
2. Across blocks: I have several blocks A -> B -> C that is a pipeline. I imagined it would work like early items would get finished processing at C while late items are still processed at A. But let's say, when I gave it like 10k items, it performed all 10k items for A, then all 10k at B, then all 10k at C. That means the first item only exited the pipeline when the last item is finished. I guess to the task scheduler all tasks are equal but to me I hope for "first response time" instead of "last response time". how do I hint the block to behave differently?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) what makes you believe that 50x4 is better than the way the scheduler divided the work? What measurements/analysis have you done? (2) If you want out of order processing set the `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` `EnsureOrdered` property to `false`, [see here: Why are tasks not running in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597087/why-tasks-are-not-going-in-parallel)

Comment: because I used to have 4 threads in loop performing the same functions, but am converting to using block.

Comment: Am actually already using EnsureOrdered false

Comment: To your first point: There a couple options: You can implement your own scheduler or you may have an issue balancing the pipeline. On your second point: If you're already setting `EnsureOrdered` to `false` then you have another issue in your pipeline. Without any code it is difficult to say more. If you could provide code and more details about why the default scheduler behavior is insufficient maybe we could provide more guidance. With enough extra detail it may be best to separate the two questions into two stand alone questions.

Comment: For 2, I guess I will try out the QueuedTaskScheduler to assign higher priority to the later blocks